# PHP - trying to create an aray with a for loop but the order isn't right

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create an arrays with 7 items. One for each day of the week. But the data coming in might be missing days. If data is missing I want the array to have "no data" for that day.

The problem is when I try to generate the array its not ordering how I would expect.

$recordArray =

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [calories] => 368
            [date] => 2018-03-04
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [calories] => 126
            [date] => 2018-03-06
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [calories] => 86
            [date] => 2018-03-07
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [calories] => 83
            [date] => 2018-03-08
        )

)
```

PHP code:

```
$xArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists($i, $recordArray)) {
        $xArray[] = $recordArray[$i]["date"];
    } else {
        $xArray[] = "no data";
    }
}
print_r($xArray);
```

Result I'm getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-03-04
    [1] => 2018-03-06
    [2] => 2018-03-07
    [3] => 2018-03-08
    [4] => no data
    [5] => no data
    [6] => no data
)
```

Result I'm expecting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-03-04
    [1] => no data
    [2] => 2018-03-06
    [3] => 2018-03-07
    [4] => 2018-03-08
    [5] => no data
    [6] => no data
)
```

Comment: Why are you expecting the second example? The first one is exactly what you've coded for, given the example input.

Comment: So, keys 0,1,2,3 exist in your array. Evidently you need some other check for days.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the correct logic:

```
// init array with "no data" value
$xArray = array_fill(0, 7, 'no data');

// iterate over your records
foreach ($recordArray as $record) {
    // From your date - get the number of week in a day
    $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($record['date']));
    // Modify the key in $xArray
    $xArray[$weekDay] = $record['date'];
}
```